# jQuery Resize Not Working Consistently

Tags: jquery

Running into an issue where my function works as expected when width of window is larger than `1024px`, works as expected when I resize lesser than `1024px`, but when I scale back up it doesn't work.

What am I trying to achieve, to run a `scrollTop` function but only when the browser is lesser than `1024px` width. I just can't seem to see the mistake I've made.

Here's my Codepen and JS code:
[Codepen](http://codepen.io/darcyvoutt/pen/aBLMZN?editors=0010)

```
function buttonClick() {
  var width = $(window).innerWidth();  
  console.log( width );

  if ( width < 960 ) {
    $('.click').on('click', function() {    
      $('body').animate({ scrollTop: $('.div2').offset().top - 10 }, 300);
    });
  }  
}


$(function() { buttonClick(); })
$(window).on('resize',function() {
  buttonClick();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that you're reassigning over and over again `buttonClick()` on every resize step - which adds therefore multiple `click` handlers to `.click`...

I would do it this way:

```
$(function() {

  function doIfLessThan960() {
    var width = $(window).innerWidth();  
    if ( width < 960 ) {
      $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('.div2').offset().top - 10 }, 300);
    }  
  }

  $('.click').on('click', doIfLessThan960);

});
```

which is: *define if button should do something only after we click it*.

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/kiqewut/1/edit?html,css,js,output)***  ← the button will work only if window width is less than 960